# Include entire directory in python setup.py data_files

Tags: python, setup.py

The data_files parameter for setup takes input in the following format:

```
setup(...
    data_files = [(target_directory, [list of files to be put there])]
    ....)
```

Is there a way for me to specify an entire directory of data instead, so I don't have to name each file individually and update it as I change implementation in my project?

I attempted to use `os.listdir()`, but I don't know how to do that with relative paths, I couldn't use `os.getcwd()` or `os.realpath(__file__)` since those don't point to my repository root correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to do that with relative paths

You need to get the path of the directory first, so...

Say you have this directory structure:

```
cur_directory
|- setup.py
|- inner_dir
   |- file2.py
```

To get the directory of the current file (in this case setup.py), use this:

```
cur_directory_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Then, to get a directory path relative to `current_directory`, just join some other directories, eg:

```
inner_dir_path = os.path.join(cur_directory_path, 'inner_dir')
```

If you want to move up a directory, just use "`..`", for example:

```
parent_dir_path = os.path.join(current_directory, '..')
```

Once you have that path, you can do `os.listdir`

For completeness:

If you want the path of a file, in this case "`file2.py`" relative to `setup.py`, you could do:

```
file2_path = os.path.join(cur_directory_path, 'inner_dir', 'file2.py')
```

Answer (score 22):

karelv has the right idea, but to answer the stated question more directly:

```
from glob import glob

setup(
    #...
    data_files = [
        ('target_directory_1', glob('source_dir/*')), # files in source_dir only - not recursive
        ('target_directory_2', glob('nested_source_dir/**/*', recursive=True)), # includes sub-folders - recursive
        # etc...
    ],
    #...
)
```

Comment: the first `glob('source_dir/**')` should be with `recursive=True` or it just shows top level https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob

Comment: A good solution. Was searching elsewhere to get this data directory done searching directory pattern.

But, my data directory looks like `'a/file1.yaml', 'a/b/file2.yaml'`. to achieve the recursive pattern, have to do 2 globs
`glob('data/*.yaml'),`
`glob('data/*/*.yaml')`

I wish if a single glob pattern can do for parent and sub-directory file scans.

Comment: use `iglob` instead of `glob` to maintain the directory structure

Answer (score 5):

```
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('inner_dir/**/*', recursive=True):
    print (filename)
```

Doing this, you get directly a list of files relative to current directory.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with directories containing nested subdirectories. The glob solutions didn't work, as they would include the directory in the list, which setup would blow up on, and in cases where I excluded matched directories, it still dumped them all in the same directory, which is not what I wanted, either. I ended up just falling back on `os.walk()`:

```
def generate_data_files():
    data_files = []
    data_dirs = ('data', 'plugins')
    for path, dirs, files in chain.from_iterable(os.walk(data_dir) for data_dir in data_dirs):
        install_dir = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'share/<my-app>/' + path)    
        list_entry = (install_dir, [os.path.join(path, f) for f in files if not f.startswith('.')])
        data_files.append(list_entry)

    return data_files
```

and then setting `data_files=generate_data_files()` in the `setup()` block.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Paul Mundt's answer,which I had to rewrite, this is what worked for me:

```py
# Iterate through all the files and subdirectories
# to build the data files array
def generate_data_files(share_path, dir):
    data_files = []
    
    for path, _, files in os.walk(dir):
        list_entry = (share_path + path, [os.path.join(path, f) for f in files if not f.startswith('.')])
        data_files.append(list_entry)

    return data_files
```

Example usage:

```py
data_files=[
        ('share/' + package_name + '/maps', glob('maps/*')),
        ('share/' + package_name + '/world', glob('world/*'))
    ] + generate_data_files('share/' + package_name + '/', 'meshes'),
```

This will add the meshes folder under `share` with all the files and subfolders recursively.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

With nested subdirectories, if you want to preserve the original directory structure, you can use `os.walk()`, as proposed in another answer.

However, an easier solution uses `pbr` library, which extends `setuptools`. See here for documentation on how to use it to install an entire directory structure:

https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/using.html#files

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30770724)