# Python setuptools Fails to Install data_files in user_config_dir

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a set of sql files in subdirectories that I wish to install from my package.

```
project\
thetask\
    __init__.py
    MainThing.py
sql\
    foo\thingone.sql
    foo\thingtwo.sql
    bar\thingone.sql
    bar\thingtwo.sql
README.md
MANIFEST.in
```

My `MANIFEST.in` contains only `recursive-include sql *.sql`.

My `setup.py` attempts to install the files in the `user_config_dir` found by `appdirs`.

```
import setuptools
import os

from appdirs import AppDirs
APP_DIRS = AppDirs("table_builder", "thetask")

def long_desc(path_to_md):
    """
    Use markdown for description on devpi server.
    """
    with open(path_to_md, "r") as _fh:
        return _fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="mything-thetask",
    version="0.1a",
    description="Tools for building TheTask tables.",
    long_description=long_desc("README.md"),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author="Someguy SomeGuysLastName",
    author_email="Someguy.SomeGuysLastName@mything.com",
    license="Proprietary",
    install_requires=[
        "xlrd",
        "pyodbc",
        "appdirs",
        ],
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    scripts=[
        "foo.py",
        "bar.py",
    ],
    data_files=[
        (APP_DIRS.user_config_dir, [
        "sql\\foo\\*.sql",
        "sql\\bar\\*.sql"
        ])
    ],
)
```

The `thetask\\table_builder` directory is created in my `AppData\\Local` directory, but `install_data` fails with:

```
    running install_data
    error: can't copy 'sql\foo\*.sql': doesn't exist or not a regular file

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\someguy\projects\testinstall\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\someguy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bmlgs1fl\\mything-thetask\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\someguy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ia0ycbsc\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\someguy\projects\testinstall\venv\include\site\python3.7\mything-thetask" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\someguy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bmlgs1fl\mything-thetask\
command failed
```

All the files I expect to see are in the `sql` directory in the `.zip` package. Where am I going wrong?

`UPDATE:` I attempted to use the specific sql files instead of a wildcard in `data_files`, which got rid of the error, but does not install any of the files in `AppData\\Local`. This is a bit frustrating.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/54337574/1548275 will answer the question. Use `glob()`.